# Current state of OpenCV hand gesture recognition?

Tags: opencv, gesture-recognition

What is the current state of hand gesture recognition in OpenCV?

I have seen great examples of being able to detect hand gestures (e.g. https://www.andol.me/1661/) but recognising gestures and performing some action (e.g. manipulating on-screen objects) seems much harder.

Does anyone know of any examples?

Thanks!

Comment: I recommand OPENNI + OPENCV + Kinect camera, which I think i more easy and accurate becasuse of the libaries of OPENNI and the extra depth information from kinect. go for kinect...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the only support in OpenCV for hand gesture recognition is exactly what Luca Del Tongo demonstrated in the video you linked to, namely [cvConvexityDefects()](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/imgproc_structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=cvconvexitydefects#cvConvexityDefects).

You might want to extract the hand mask using color-space filtering (as suggested in the video), and using ML classifiers for detecting the actual gesture. There have been several papers that have done this, though this is not currently implemented *as-such* in OpenCV.

Comment: For anyone making an android app, it's in the java api under Imgproc called convexityDefects(): http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#convexityDefects(org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint,%20org.opencv.core.MatOfInt,%20org.opencv.core.MatOfInt4)

Answer (score 0):

cvConvexityDefects() is the key step following the hand segmentation as done in [andol.info/hci/1661.htm](http://www.andol.info/hci/1661.htm)