# Make a program than can use a Video Camera and Recognise Gestures

Tags: c#, java, camera, gestures

I want to make a program preferably in C# or Java that can access a video camera and recognize gestures. I have done programming before but this is the first time i require access to a pluggable hardware and control it. I dont want the whole program but just that how should i start.
How to make a programming language access a hardware.
Do i need external api for the hardware manufacturer
How can a camera be made to recognise gestured etc.

Comment: If you have a question please include source code so it can be answered. This does not fit the type of question this site is for.

Comment: Have a look at OpenCV library (there's a wrapper for both [C#](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) and java). It should be able to connect to cameras and webcams,and it can be used for gesture recognition ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094602/current-state-of-opencv-hand-gesture-recognition))

Comment: I think you are way over your head in this matter, it is not the camera that recognises gestures, it is your software that should do it.  You will need a lot of image processing skills.

Comment: this question is way to vague.  First, choose a language.  Next, do some experiments.  Last, provide questions about your experiments with detailed information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If writing in C# then you may want to look at Microsoft Kinect and the libraries and drivers they have for it.  This would be much easier and more robust than writing a solution yourself using a camera.

Answer (score 0):

You've asked two questions.

Do a Google search on "open source video camera api" (without the quotes).  You should find one or more libraries that will work with a C# or Java application.

Getting your software to recognize gestures will be orders of magnitude more complicated.  Do a Google search on "recognizing video gestures" (without the quotes).  Some libraries and explanations of what's involved will be listed.