# Gesture Recognition OpenCV ( for media player )

Tags: opencv, media-player, tracking, emgucv, gesture-recognition

Can someone please help me out with how exactly to start from scratch for using OpenCV for hand gesture recognition? We're basically creating a media player that can function with hand gestures (simple functions such as play, pause, volume up/down etc).

I've installed OpenCV and also EmguCV after visiting one of the links mentioned in the questions, but I need to know how exactly do I get webcam on to detect my hand and gestures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think OpenCV has an all-in-one function that will "just do hand recognition" for you. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094602/current-state-of-opencv-hand-gesture-recognition) will give you some more information.

If you're serious about building a hand tracking system out of OpenCV library calls, then [this documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html) (and especially [cvConvexityDefects](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#cvConvexityDefects)) might be a good place to start.

Comment: I went through the thread that you have provided and I even downloaded his code and went through his method. I did understand a bit of it but since I'm just learning from scratch I need to get my OpenCV running to detect my gestures which is still not happening, I've coded something but once my webcam starts it just appears black, not detecting any of my movements. I'm still figuring out how to fix this and then I will go through the documentation y'all have provided. Thanks a lot for the help! Will post here if I face any more issues!

Comment: Don't forget to one of the answers as best (you'll see the white checkmark turn green).  @user1650978

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of online tutorials about using OpenCV and EmguCV for tracking and gesture recognition. I would suggest that you google for a few research papers on the subject. These will help you get started with the various solutions that you can use and improve upon.

One way would be to segment out the hand using skin detection and then find contours followed by a convex hull. There is a library called [cvBlob](http://code.google.com/p/cvblob/) which may help you out with tracking. To interface it with a media player, you can possibly use VLC remote interface.

[OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/) is also a great place to find out about various functions which might help you out

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've gathered a few research papers will go through them. Is there any book that you can suggest on OpenCV that will help me too?

Comment: There aren't many books that will help out for openCV. [link](http://www.laganiere.name/opencvCookbook/)Here is  book which might help out. Btw, you could probably use VLC media player's remote interface to actually interface your program with VLC.